# WxPython Login Function

Tags: python, function, user-interface, authentication, wxpython

I'm writing a GUI and I'm trying to make a login screen before my main GUI screen but i cant figure out the right way to do this

First i tried to structure it like this:

```
class GUI(wx.Frame):
    #GUI
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        state = 1
        if state ==1:
            #Login screen code
        elif state == 2:
            #Main Screen code
```

But that didn't work nothing popped up

So i tried creating a whole different smaller window that pops up before the main window but couldn't get that to work

So my question is how can i make a login screen for my GUI correctly

Thank You!!

Comment: `__init__` is only run once, and since each time you start `GUI` the state will be `1` no matter what the `GUI` will always show up the same thing. Show us more code, be more logical when you create your classes.. for instance, if you re-use this class make `state` a parameter. And perhaps put `state #2` in a function or something?

Comment: it changes to state 2 on the press of the OK button on the login screen but its not even showing the login screen

Comment: How do you instantiate `GUI`, and do you even call `wx.Frame.__init__` anywhere?

Could you please post your full code because this code is useless to us (no offence, but it's so vague). It's like saying "i'm having a problem with my hot-dog" without us knowing if you're a vegetarian or having a HOT dog.. Or if you're just missing your bun to your hot-dog :/

Comment: youre right, i just dont want to show all the 500 + lines yes i call `wx.Frame.__init__`. the GUI works already but i need to add a login screen somehow and the information from the persons account will be displayed in the GUI so i need to get the information before i show my main screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I open a Preferences window on first-launch for [GooeyPi](https://github.com/multiphrenic/GooeyPi): My PyInstaller GUI front-end. This can easily be adapted to have a password dialog or frame. I separate out into two functions: check if the user has setup preferences, and open the preferences window. This allows them to change preferences later. I use `ShowModal` to prevent the user from using the application until they are set.

```
class GooeyPi(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GooeyPi, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((460,350))
        self.SetTitle('GooeyPi - PyInstaller GUI')
        self.Show()
        self.CheckFirstRun() # Checks for first run here.

    .....

    def CheckFirstRun(self):
        config = controller.getConfig()
        if config['pyidir'] == '':
            ...
            self.OnPreferences(None)
    ....

    def OnPreferences(self, e):
        prefdlg = pref.Preferences(None, title='Edit Preferneces')
        prefdlg.ShowModal()
        prefdlg.Destroy()
```

and pref.Preferences is definied in a separate module:

```
class Preferences(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Preferences, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((380,290))
        self.SetTitle("Preferences")

    def InitUI(self):
         you_get_the_idea...
```

Comment: this is helpful what i did is created the login and showed it first then the main window was called on the button push event thank you though ill accept youre answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the builtin wx.PasswordEntryDialog and something as simple as Showing or Hiding the main window based on the entry from the password dialog. You could even put the wx.PasswordEntryDialog in a while loop. Something like (untested)

```
self.Hide()
password = "a passphrase"
entered_password = None
while entered_password != password:
    dialog = wx.PasswordEntryDialog(self, "Enter the password", "Please enter the password")
    ret_value = dialog.ShowModal()
    if ret_value == wx.ID_OK:
        entered_password = dialog.GetValue()
    else:
         self.Close(True)
    dialog.Destroy()
# self.Show()
```